# overflow: auto; within flexbox (new spec)

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

I am trying to migrate a design to the new flexbox spec (`display: -webkit-flex;` instead of `display: webkit-box;`). Although the `overflow: auto;` property seems to be being ignored unless I set an explicit height on the container being overflowed.

**Working Examples:**

[Implementation with old spec](http://codepen.io/WilsonPage/pen/lIeCG)

[Implementation with new spec](http://codepen.io/WilsonPage/pen/kAyfv)

*Am I doing something wrong, or is this new spec not fully finished yet?*

Answer (score 2):

Half a year later: I struggled with similar issue and have to say it's more likely a **bug**.

Unfortunately, neither current version of *Chrome 25* nor *Safari 6.0.2* does handle this case yet.

Although, if you check out the newest *Chrome 27 canary* version you can see that it's seems to be fixed there.

The only one code change which I had to apply to your example was to remove `height: 100%;` property on bottom containers and add some sort of hack which is `min-height: 0;` set for main bottom container (which by the way for some reason can be also replaced with `height: 0;` property).

[CodePen fork](http://codepen.io/pawelsledzikowski/pen/DLwby)

Comment: Chrome 26 has also this bug. Fixed with the `min-height:0`  hack